# React JS trying to return a Div

Tags: reactjs

I have a JavaScript object that is being passed in via props and I would like to iterate over them to create a new div using the name and the value.  I've tried using a forEach but found out that it doesnt return anything

I'm passing in a JS Object

```
let example = {all: 1255, rentals: 396, pip: 236, pm: 375, substatusCV: 0}
```

I know this probably looks terrible but it's my first go :)

```
import React from "react";

function Navbar(props){
 
  return (
    <div>
      {
        props.resp.all > '' ? ( 
            Object.entries(props.resp).forEach(([name, value]) => {
            // I'm able to return the key / value here but forEach doesnt return a value 
            // so I'm unsure how to create and return the div
              console.log(`${name}: ${value}`)

              // <div > {name} ({value})</div>
            })
          )
          : 'Loading'
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Try using map istead of foreach. array.map((el, i) => <div key={i}>Some text</div>). This is what you need here.

Comment: From what i read online, map only works for an array right? So i wouldnt be able to get the name as well?  I need to be able to pull the name and the value.   Is that possible?  an example of the javascript object would be  { all: 1255, rentals: 396, pip: 236, pm: 375, substatusCV: 0 }

Comment: You are using foreach and object entries returns an array of key value pair so map will work. So you can use map. eg. Object.entries(props.resp).map(([name, value], i) => <div key={i}>{name} {value}</div>); And if you only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me put this in formal answer format.

Here in your code you are using Object.entries.

Object.entries returns a array of key value pair seprated in an array. So for your object `{all: 1255, rentals: 396, pip: 236, pm: 375, substatusCV: 0}` you will receive an array `[["all", 1255], ["rentals", 396], ["pip", 236], ["pm", 375], ["substatusCV", 0]]`.

so now you can use all the array functions on this array. So your code will became.

```
 import React from "react";


function Navbar(props){
 
    return (
        <div>
            
            {
                props.resp.all > ''? ( 

                    Object.entries(props.resp).map(([name, value], index) => {
                        return <div > {name} ({value})</div>
                    })    

                ) : 'Loading'
            }

        </div>
        )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close but need to use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function instead of `forEach` as well as needing to `return` the div.

```
import React from "react";


function Navbar(props){
 
    return (
        <div>
            
            {
                props.resp.all > ''? ( 

                    Object.entries(props.resp).map(([name, value]) => {
                        //I'm able to return the key / value here but forEach doesnt return a value so I'm unsure how to create and return the div

                        console.log(`${name}: ${value}`)

                        return <div > {name} ({value})</div>
                       
                    })    

                )

                  : 'Loading'
            
            }

        </div>
        )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: This only works for an array right? I'm using a JS Object                                                         { all: 1255, rentals: 396, pip: 236, pm: 375, substatusCV: 0 }

Comment: Object.entries returns an array of key value pairs. In your js object, it will return `[["all", 1255], ["rentals", 396], ["pip", 236], ["pm", 375], ["substatusCV", 0]]`